# Functions operating on two lists

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, racket-student-languages

I am working on a Racket program for a class and I am totally stumped as to
how to implement one of the features.

The program uses Big-Bang and is supposed to implement a simple Space Invaders game.

I have everything working except one piece, and that is - how to handle the case
when a missile collides with an invader. The reason I'm struggling is that I don't
know how to write a function where I have two lists of arbitrary size, and I have
to check the fields of each object in one list with each object in another list and
remove an object in each list if they have the same values.

The world state is the game:

```
(define-struct game (invaders missiles tank))
```

where invaders and missiles are
both lists.

To produce the next state of the game, I implement a function called 'tock'.

Normally, I would just do:

```
(define (tock s)
  (make-game (next-invaders (game-invaders s)) 
             (next-missiles (game-missiles s))
             (next-tank (game-tank s)))
```

But since the contents of the invaders and missiles lists might impact each other due to a collision, I can't simply update the positions independently and move on, I have to remove any collisions and then update the positions.

So I've tried:

```
(define (tock s)
  (make-game (check-collision (game-invaders s) 
                              (game-missiles s) 
                              (game-tank s))
```

But this makes check-collision take a tank, which it doesn't need.

```
(define (tock s)
  (make-game (next-invaders (game-invaders s) (game-missiles s)) 
             (next-missiles (game-missiles s) (game-invaders s)) 
             (next-tank (game-tank s))))
```

In this version, I have a function called `next-invaders` which takes the list of invaders and missiles, and a function
called `next-missiles` which takes the list of missiles and invaders. The first function checks each invader against each missile, attempts to remove any collided invaders and returns the remaining invaders. The second function checks each missile against each invader and attempts to remove any collided missiles and returns the remaining missiles. The answers should be the same, but it's duplicate work and I'm worried about a possible race condition. I don't know how else to construct a single expression where one function only needs two fields and the other one needs three
and I still wind up producing the next state of the game.

Here's an example of `next-invaders`. If there are no invaders, it does nothing. If there are invaders but no missiles,
it just moves each invader `(move-invader)` and recursively calls itself to iterate through all invaders. If there
are both missiles and invaders, then I check for a collision between the first invader in the list, and every
missile in the list; so check collision is recursive.

```
(define (next-invaders loi lom)
  (cond [(empty? loi) empty]
        [(empty? lom) (move-invader (first loi) (next-invaders (rest loi) lom))]
        [(check_collision (first loi) lom) 
         (next-invaders (cons (rest loi) empty) lom)]
        [else
         (move-invader (first loi)
                       (next-invaders (rest loi) lom))]))
```

Is the 'answer' to `check-collision` the correct way to "remove" the collided invader from the list of invaders?

```
(define (check_collision i lom)
  (cond [(empty? lom) false]
        [(and (<= (- (missile-x (first lom)) (invader-x i)) HIT-RANGE)
              (<= (- (missile-y (first lom)) (invader-y i)) HIT-RANGE)) 
         true]
        [else (check_collision i (rest lom))]))
```

### Is this the correct way to test each element of each list against one another?

Update: Still going in circles on this problem. check-collision works and invader-function works, but when I return to missile-function, I don't know how to indicate that a missile needs to be deleted in the case where there was a collision detected in invader-function.

```
(define-struct invader (x y dx))
;; Invader is (make-invader Number Number Number)
;; interp. the invader is at (x, y) in screen coordinates
;;         the invader along x by dx pixels per clock tick

(define-struct missile (x y))
;; Missile is (make-missile Number Number)
;; interp. the missile's location is x y in screen coordinates

(define-struct collision (invaders missiles))

(define (tock s)
  (make-game (handle-invaders (collision-invaders (next-invaders-and-missiles (make-collision (game-invaders s) (game-missiles s)))))
             (handle-missiles (collision-missiles (next-invaders-and-missiles (make-collision (game-invaders s) (game-missiles s)))))
             (handle-tank (game-tank s))))

(define (next-invaders-and-missiles c)
  (cond [(and (empty? (collision-invaders c)) (empty? (collision-missiles c))) (make-collision empty empty)]
    [(or (empty? (collision-invaders c)) (empty? (collision-missiles c))) (make-collision (collision-invaders c) (collision-missiles c))]
    [else
     (missile-function (make-collision (collision-invaders c) (collision-missiles c)))]))


;; Collision -> list Of Missiles
;; produce an updated listOf Missiles taking collisions into account
(define (missile-function c)
  (cond [(empty? (collision-missiles c)) (make-collision (collision-invaders c) empty)]
    [else
     (if (< (length (invader-function (first (collision-missiles c)) (collision-invaders c))) (length (collision-invaders c)))
         (make-collision (collision-invaders c) (remove (first (collision-missiles c)) (collision-missiles c)))
         (missile-function (make-collision (collision-invaders c) (rest (collision-missiles c)))))]))


;; Missile, listOf Invaders -> listOf Invaders
;; produce an updated listOf Invaders taking collisions into account
(define (invader-function m loi)
  (cond [(empty? loi) empty]
    [else
     (if (check-collision? (first loi) m)
         (remove (first loi) loi)
         (invader-function m (rest loi)))]))

;; Invader, Missile -> Boolean
;; produce true if the coordinates of a missile are within HIT-RANGE of     the coordinates of an invader
(define (check-collision? i m)
  (and (<= (- (missile-x m) (invader-x i)) HIT-RANGE) (<= (- (missile-y m) (invader-y i)) HIT-RANGE)))
```

Comment: One particular issue with collision detection is the order by which you iterate over objects: you generally do *not* want collision be dependant on the (arbitrary) order of elements in your lists. Typically, an *arbiter* function groups collisions as collision objects, and then the collision is resolved for a group of objects, to ensure determinism. That's probably not important in your case, however.

Comment: Which exact language are you using? Are you using Racket, Scheme, Beginning Student Language, Intermediate Student Language, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't reviewed all the code, but the general solution is to have one function that takes the lists of missiles and invaders, checks for all the collisions, and then returns both updated lists by returning a pair of lists. So something like this:

```
(define (tock s)
  (let* [(next (next-invaders-and-missiles (game-invaders s) (game-missiles s)))
         (next-invaders (first next))
         (next-missiles (rest next))]
    (make-game next-invaders next-missiles (game-tank s))))

(define (next-invaders-and-missiles loi lom)
  ... ;; code that finds collisions and removes them from both lists
  (cons new-loi new-lom))
```

Comment: What does let* do? I've never seen that notation before. It looks like this is a way to call more than one function in a function, which I didn't know how to do.

Comment: It's like `let`, but it performs the bindings sequentially instead of in parallel. So the binding of `next-invaders` and `nexxt-missiles` can refer back to `next`.

Comment: If I didn't do that I'd have to use nested `let`, or bind `next-invaders` and `next-missiles` to dummy values and then reassign them with `set!`, or just use `car` and `cdr` in the call to `make-game`.

Comment: So, 'car' and 'cdr' have meaning in Racket? Those are new to me too. Also, I know how to check one item from loi against each item of lom, but i don't know how to check each item of loi against each item of lom.

Comment: julieb: `car` is like `first`, and `cdr` is like `rest`. Barmar: I think julieb is actually using one of the Racket student languages, like BSL or ISL. Those don't have `set!`, and they use `first` and `rest` instead of `car` and `cdr`.

Comment: @AlexKnauth Thanks, I'n not really familiar with the student language restrictions, but I've changed the answer to use `first` and `rest`. I don't really like using `rest` when the cons is holding a pair rather than being part of a list, but if the language forces me....

Comment: You're right, I'm using BSL and it has first and rest.

Comment: I'm still not sure how to implement (next-invaders-and-missiles loi lom). I know how to check for collisions between a missile and invader, but I don't know how to hold an invader constant, iterate through each missile location, then move to the next invader, and iterate through each missile again.                                  (define (next-invaders-and-missiles loi lom)
  (if (and (<= (- (missile-x (first lom)) (invader-x (first loi))) HIT-RANGE) (<= (- (missile-y (first lom)) (invader-y (first loi))) HIT-RANGE))
      (cons new-loi new-lom))

Comment: You'll probably want to use nested loops. The outer loop loops through missiles, the inner loop loops through invaders, and then it checks whether the current missile has hit the current invader. If so, it removes them each from their respective lists.

Comment: Like this? I still can't get it to work, have been going in circles. I can only use Beginning Student Language w/List Abbrev
     
(define (loop_over_missiles loi lom)
  (cond [(empty? lom) empty]
        [else
         (if (check-collision? (first loi) (first lom))
             (remove (first lom) lom)
             (loop_over_missiles loi (rest lom)))]))

(define (loop_over_invaders loi lom)
  (cond [(empty? loi) empty]
        [else
         (if (check-collision? (first loi) (first lom))
             (remove (first loi) loi)
             (loop_over_invaders (rest loi) lom))]))

Comment: I'm sorry, the 'Add Comment' function doesn't give me any options for formatting. If you copy and paste it into a text file, the structure is visible.

Comment: If you need to post a large block of text, add it to the question.

Comment: Ok, that's what I did. I show the new code after the "Update: " statement.